# Stubbing of react-router hooks like 'useLocation' is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, enzyme

I am trying to write unit test for the React functional component which has router hooks `useLocation()` like below.

```
//index.js
function MyComponent(props) {
  const useQuery = () => new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
   const status = useQuery().get('status');

  if (status === 'success') {
    return <ShowStatus message="OK" secret={props.secret} />;
  } else {
    return <ShowStatus message="NOT OK" secret={props.secret} />;
  }
}

//index.spec.js
describe('Test MyComponent', () => {
  it('should send OK when success', () => {
     sinon.stub(reactRouter, 'useLocation').returns({
        search: {
            status: 'success'
        }
     });
     const props = { secret: 'SECRET_KEY' };
     const wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<MyComponent.WrappedComponent {...props}/>);

     expect(wrapper.type()).to.have.length(MyComponent);
     expect(wrapper.props().message).to.equal('OK');
     expect(wrapper.props().secret).to.equal(props.secret);
  });

  it('should send NOT OK when error', () => {
     sinon.stub(reactRouter, 'useLocation').returns({
        search: {
            status: 'error'
        }
     });
     const props = { secret: 'SECRET_KEY' };
     const wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<MyComponent.WrappedComponent {...props}/>);

     expect(wrapper.type()).to.have.length(MyComponent);
     expect(wrapper.props().message).to.equal('NOT OK);
     expect(wrapper.props().secret).to.equal(props.secret);
  });
});
```

Even I am stubbing `useLocation` I am getting error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
at useLocation (node_modules\react-router\modules\hooks.js:28:10)
```

I am trying to test `ShowStatus` component is render with right props based on the query param.

Any suggestion/help is appreciated.

**Update:**
I am noticing even though I am importing from `react-router-dom` in both prod and test code. I am seeing prod one is taking from `react-router`.

Comment: any update on this? I still am having trouble mocking/stubbing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MemoryRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/MemoryRouter) component wraps your component is better than stub `useLocation` hook.

> keeps the history of your “URL” in memory (does not read or write to the address bar). Useful in tests and non-browser environments like React Native.

We can provide the "URL" to your component under test via [initialEntries](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/MemoryRouter/initialentries-array) props.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export function ShowStatus({ message, secret }) {
  return <div>{message}</div>;
}

export function MyComponent(props) {
  const useQuery = () => new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
  const status = useQuery().get('status');

  if (status === 'success') {
    return <ShowStatus message="OK" secret={props.secret} />;
  } else {
    return <ShowStatus message="NOT OK" secret={props.secret} />;
  }
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router';
import { MyComponent, ShowStatus } from './';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should send OK when success', () => {
    const props = { secret: 'SECRET_KEY' };
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[{ search: '?status=success' }]}>
        <MyComponent {...props} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    expect(wrapper.find(ShowStatus).props().message).toEqual('OK');
    expect(wrapper.find(MyComponent).props().secret).toEqual(props.secret);
  });

  it('should send NOT OK when error', () => {
    const props = { secret: 'SECRET_KEY' };
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[{ search: '?status=error' }]}>
        <MyComponent {...props} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(wrapper.find(ShowStatus).props().message).toEqual('NOT OK');
    expect(wrapper.find(MyComponent).props().secret).toEqual(props.secret);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/59829930/index.test.tsx (8.239 s)
  MyComponent
    ✓ should send OK when success (55 ms)
    ✓ should send NOT OK when error (8 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.003 s
```

package versions:

```json
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```